# How to store sensor readings in aws greengrass?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot-greengrass

I'm trying to build an aws greengrass setup with 100 sensors connected. Is it possible to store sensor readings in greengrass locally when the internet connection is lost ?

Is there an inbuilt Dynamodb alternative in AWS greengrass ?

What is the best approach to store sensor readings when the internet connectivity is lost in aws greengrass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways to do it:

1) Your user lambdas can access to AWS services directly from GGC to push data to DDB. GGC has a builtin mechanism to get the credential tokens on behalf of user-lambdas. You need to set up the group role to allow the user-lambdas to so and you can see here [config-iam-roles.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/config-iam-roles.html).

2) You can use the new stream manager feature in release 1.10 to the job. [stream manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/stream-manager.html)